# SAPUI5 / OpenUI5: More than one app in a portal

Tags: javascript, android, ios, sapui5

I have developed some SAPUI5 mobile apps and  I'd like to merge them into a portal (with tiles) so I can switch between them as a "reputation".

Now I would like to know, what would be the "best" way to implement this case?

At the moment the apps have got a controller and views. My first idea was to build a "portal-app" which includes all the views of the other apps with an own controller but then I noticed that the performance has decreased (because all resources (OData-models etc.) load when starting the portal-app).

I also tried to link them (all with their own index.html) but this case seems not to be the right one.

So is there a way to load the views dynamicly or a whole app and how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, SAP's official solution for this problem is called SAP Fiori Launchpad. However, it's much more complex to set up (you need an underlying application server which holds SAP Fiori. You need to handle user roles and assign applications to roles). However, it's great for inspiration. ([Here you can check it](https://www.sapfioritrial.com/sites?helpset=trial&sap-client=001))

You can create a separate component which holds the references to other applications. Your applications can be referenced from Tiles.

I don't know the current implementation of your applications, but it's recommended to implement them as [components](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/958ead51e2e94ab8bcdc90fb7e9d53d0.html) (UI components if they have visual representation).

With components, you will be able to use Routing (navigating between views, or even components using hashes (urls)), which helps you to manage resources and services properly. With this you can prevent unwanted odata requests as well.

It can be a big step forward from a simple application architecture, but it's worth it.

Of course, you can implement one simple application without components. In this case you can experience the mentioned performance issues. Consider to move data intensive operations into event handlers and perform these tasks asynchronously.